# Right align Superfish menu - and stop it jumping around

Tags: css, superfish, submenu

I would really like to stop the menu items jumping around [on this site](http://carolineelisa.com/wordpress/) as the parent item expands to fit its child.

I can get it looking how I want when I add this CSS, forcing the menu items to have fixed widths:

```
/*Menu item 1*/
#menu-item-117 .sub-menu {right: -125px;}
/*Menu item 2*/
#menu-item-73 {width:45px;}
#menu-item-73 .sub-menu {width:980px!important;right: -10px;}
/*Menu item 3*/
#menu-item-122 {width:65px;}
#menu-item-122 .sub-menu{width:980px!important;right: 165px;}
```

However, this is clearly not ideal, as the menu needs to be dynamic...

Is there a way to achieve what I want via CSS? I hope so!

I am using the Superfish menu that comes with [Theme Hybrid](http://themehybrid.com/themes/hybrid) for Wordpress.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get your point .. let's see again.

This build uses `position: relative/absolute;` instead of `float: right/left;` and it has one flaw mentioned below.

However I haven't test this in old browsers including IE (tested in Chrome & Firefox), but I hope this may provide you some idea to implement it. :)

```
#primary-menu .menu /* new rule */ {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px; /* The flaw is you have to fix the menu's height here */
}

#primary-menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

#primary-menu li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.sub-menu {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #244563;
    clear: both;
    display: none;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 5px 0 !important;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    text-align: right;
    top: 30px !important;
    width: 700px !important;
}

.sub-menu li {
    display: inline !important;
    float: none !important;
    padding: 10px 0 !important;
    width: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Phatograph, but perhaps I didn't explain myself properly. I want the dropdown effect to remain, with the submenus on their own line. I just don't want say 'Work' to jump to the left when you rollover 'Lab' or 'About', and 'Lab' when you rollover 'About'.

Comment: Let me try it again, see above :)

Comment: That's it! With a couple of tweaks, it is doing pretty much what I want now. Thank you.